# linux + find word/string in file under directory

Tags: linux, find

I have the following command

```
find /var -type f -exec grep "param1" {} \; -print
```

With this command I can find the param1 string in any file under /var but the time that it take for this is very long.

I need another possibility to find string in file but much more faster then my example

Comment: @yael: How long is "very long?" A minute, an hour, a day? Maybe you can help us answer your earlier ambiguous questions before we start on this one, yes?

Comment: Please stop posting the same question on both StackOverflow and SuperUser.

Answer (score 5):

You could try using grep directly as in

```
grep -R "param1" /var/*
```

Comment: or even `grep -R "param1" /var`

Comment: +1 definitely the way to go, and you can also use the `-l` option to print only the names of the matching files rather than the actual matching lines within the files.

Answer (score 1):

fast search is mostly achieved by having an "index" of the content, kind of a "lookup table". there are exist some free search engines which build an index of input files and give you very, very fast results:

- [lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/)
- [xapian](http://xapian.org/)

i doubt that you want to go that way, but just to give you another option :)

Comment: indexed content is normally done only for stuff that isn't expected to change significantly. And by "significantly", I mean adding hundreds of lines every time it boots, such as files under /var.

Comment: @Kevin M: "i doubt that you want to go that way" was intentionally put there. shall i put the drawback of the indexed approach into the answer?

Answer (score 1):

There are a a couple factors at work here:

**First**, by using `-exec`, find is spawning a new process for `grep` for every file it finds.

This can be managed either by using xargs as in Felipe Alvarez's answer (I wrote a [blog post](http://wemmick.blogspot.com/2005/01/geeky-friday-find-xargs-grep-and.html) about this 5+ years ago) or by using `-exec grep param1 {} +` (note the `+` instead of `\;`). When using `+`, "the command line is built  by  appending each  selected file name at the end; the total number of invocations of the command will  be  much  less  than  the  number  of matched  files" (from [find man page](http://www.rtalabel.org/find.html))

**Second**, the number and size of files under `/var` is potentially very large.

Can you add parameters in addition to `-type f` to limit the files you're searching. `find` has options to limit by time, owner, name pattern, etc. For example, you could do:

```
find /var -type f -name "access*log" -mtime -7 -exec grep param1 {} +
```

That will find files modified in the last seven days with names starting with "access" and ending with "log". Only those matching files will be part of the exec/grep.

Answer (score 0):

find ...[blah]..... -print0 | xargs -0 grep -e "regex"

Answer (score 0):

I advise to use:

```
grep -RInis "param1" /var
```

For more details see

```
man grep
```

If speed is of such importance, you might want to consider fgrep, which might not prove to be faster depending on the implementation.